# SQL 2005 Timeout Expired `

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am facing a SQL Timeout Expiration error while executing it through a website . The actual bug shows

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

What i have tried

1. Goto SQL Server Settings and changed the Execution time from 600 to 0(for unlimited)
2. Also tried Timeout key on connection string in configuration file \

No luck ! Any options to try out

Comment: What is the query you are executing? Also what is the data row size?

Comment: Is the query in transaction ? If it is you should increase the transaction timeout too.

Comment: `Goto SQL Server Settings and changed the Execution time` The SQL Server hasn't an execution timeout option. You should change the timeout period for your SQL command. What technology do you use to connect with SQL Server?

Comment: @Matt Im using a Select statement and the data row size is around 10000 rows

Comment: Your first response to this error should be to tune the query, not extend the time out! If your application won't wait for a response from the server it is unlikely your users will. If you post your query, relevant table definition and relevant indexes, and your execution plan then someone may be able to assist in tuning your query.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have not appliedany **locks** in table, locking also can create such issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the timeout on the SQL command,

```
SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("myStoredProcedure", myConnection);
myCmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
```

But you really need to be looking at the query and/or your table structure, you shouldn't need to extend the timeout.